# Updating a PlayonLinux Windows 7/8 via .msu file?

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I am trying to install a VC++2015 application in a new PlayOnLinux virtual drive.

The application complains that my Windows version is not up to date and that I should turn on Windows Update (funny!) or download a .msu file.

After some research I found out that .msu file can be run via the wusa.exe command (kind of msiexec equivalent I suppose). However when I try that via the Run Exe file button or Open a command line, it fails!

I have also tried the [WSUS Offline Update](http://download.wsusoffline.net/) but I have some errors...

I have seen a post where @JayDin manages to use this and some system script to update a MSOffice installation.

Do you know if there is an easier way to maintain a Windows under a Wine/PoL installation?
Else I will try to go step by step with the errors I can find.

Thanks for your help.
William

Comment: Did you ever get this issue sorted? [I based my bat file on this](https://forums.wsusoffline.net/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=5479&p=18061&hilit=extract+msp) but I not sure how well it worked.